# ta.barssince identify after a certain value

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

this is the script:

```
closeAboveConv = color.white
    e1 = ta.barssince(not(close > EMALine))
    e2 = ta.barssince(close > EMALine)
    int barsSincecloseAboveConv = 0
    if close > EMALine
        closeAboveConv := green
        barsSincecloseAboveConv := e1
    else
        closeAboveConv := red
        barsSincecloseAboveConv := e2
```

Essentially, it counts the bars since the conditions (e1 or e2) have been true, it highlights the table cell as green or red, respectively. I hope to make it so that it highlights the table cell as deeper green or deeper red or whatever color after the bars count reached a certain value, like after >15 bars since condition have been true. Thank you